# Do the Nagle Algorith and Delayed ACK's affect TCP Connection Setup?

Tags: language-agnostic, tcp, network-programming, network-protocols

Do the client's SYN and the servers SYN+ACK get delayed by Nagle?  Will the client's ACK of the server's SYN get delayed?

Will connect return after rtt+spt or will it take rtt + spt + 2x Nagle Delay?

Or more generally, how do the Nagle Algorith and Delayed ACK's affect TCP Connection Setup?

Answer (score 4):

No, NAGLE does not effect SYN or SYN+ACK.  Neither does delayed ACK (logically enough, you want the SYN+ACK to come back as quick as possible, and there is no congestion state to cause a holdoff yet anyway).

Comment: @Andrew:  What you're saying makes sense.  Do you have any references to standards or anything like that?

Comment: RFC 2581 section 4.2 is the basic reference, but I'd read a stack implementation to really see the details of this; FreeBSD is pretty easy to read, the Linux stack drowns the algorithm in abstractions.